# TypeError: classification_report() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, metrics, multilabel-classification, crf

> return metrics.classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels, **kwargs)
> TypeError: classification_report() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

We are currently training a crf model and we wanted to get the classification report of the metrics but we got this error.

we tried to do this instead:

> from sklearn.metrics import classification report
> print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, labels='labels'))

and got this error:

> ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead - the MultiLabelBinarizer transformer can convert to this format.

So then we tried to convert it to a sparse matrix and also using the MultiLabel Binarizer and nothing worked. We can't seem to figure it out. does anyone know how this works?

```
# metrics on test dataset
print("For Testing Set: ")
print("F1 score:          {}".format(metrics.flat_f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')))
print("Precision score:   {}".format(metrics.flat_precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')))
print("Recall score:      {}".format(metrics.flat_recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted', labels='labels')))

print(metrics.flat_classification_report(y_test, y_pred, labels='labels', digits=3))
```

above is our sample code

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the version of scikit-learn in your environment can cause this issue. I encountered this error on Google Colab, which uses scikit-learn version 1.2.2 at the time of writing. After downgrading the scikit-learn to version 0.24.2, I was able to get `flat_classification_report()` to work.

Here is the command that I used to downgrade the scikit-learn package on Colab:

`!pip install --force-reinstall --no-dependencies "scikit-learn==0.24.2"`

Restart your runtime after running this command.

If you are training the model on your local machine, I assume that reinstalling or downgrading scikit-learn to version 0.24.2 would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is raised in git https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/sklearn-crfsuite/issues/66

But its not resolved till now.
I was able to alternative :
pip install git+https://github.com/MeMartijn/updated-sklearn-crfsuite.git#egg=sklearn_crfsuite.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the sklearn classification report directly like below:

```
from sklearn_crfsuite import metrics    
from sklearn_crfsuite.utils import flatten
from sklearn import metrics as skmetrics

# Get data for X_test and y_test
# Load CRF Model

y_pred = crf.predict(X_test)
    
y_test_flat = flatten(y_test)
y_pred_flat = flatten(y_pred)
    
print(skmetrics.classification_report(y_test_flat, y_pred_flat))
```